# node-thermal-printer runs println inconsistently

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am trying to print an array and I run into an bug. I was able to narrow it down to the following bit:

```
for (var a = 0; a < 10; a++) {
  printName("Name");
};
```

and here is my `printName` function (this is a specific function for thermal printers from https://github.com/Klemen1337/node-thermal-printer):

```
function printName(name){
  printer.println(name);
  printer.drawLine();
  printer.cut();
  printer.execute();
}
```

When I set `a < 4` it prints `Name` **10** times, for `a < 2` it prints **3** times. `printer.execute` writes `Print done` in console and is displayed only 4 or 2 times respectively, while the printer prints far more.

If I add `console.log`, I also see the log just for the max times I set `a < X`.

Any help will be much appreciated!

Kind regards,

Emite

Comment: It seems that your calls are accumulating, which is probably because the docs say `printer.execute()` executes the commands, but doesn't mention clearing the command queue. So the first time you call `printer.execute()` there is one `println` call, the next time there is `2`, then `3`, then `4`, hence you get `1 + 2 + 3 + 4 = 10` calls to `println` the final time `printer.execute()`. I'm not familiar with that printer library, but you could try starting your function with `printer.clear();`.

Comment: I would suggest asking the `node-thermal-printer` maintainers.

Comment: looking through the source code, I believe that @Paulpro is correct.  The data is put into a buffer, and while `.execute()` sends the buffer to the printer, it does not clear the buffer after.  Calling the function and adding more data to the buffer will create duplicated data.  Either use `printer.clear()` or modify the library / contact the library maintainers about fixing the `.execute()` function.